# Variable result of an async/await process: do we always wait for it?

Tags: javascript

When a variable is a result of an `await` process, does the process wait for the "waiting" variable all the time?

I tried and it waits all the time, but I'd like to know if there are any exceptions.

For example:

```
async imageUpload(id) {
        let formImageData = new FormData()
        formImageData.append('file', this.formImageFile)
        let res = await axios.post( '/db/imageUpload', {
          formImageData, 
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        })
        .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
        alert(res)
    },
```

in my experience -but I am a beginner- "res" is always ready for the alert, is there a case in which the alert in `variable = await resultFunction(); alert(variable)` wouldn't be waiting for the `resultFunction()` and thus the alert request would be faster and "variable" will be `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, await waits until the `Promise` returned by `axios.post` is resolved.

But be careful!

if `axios.post` gets rejected `catch` gets called and then `res` will be the value that was returned by your `catch` function.

For example:

`axios.post` encounters a 404 error and rejects the `Promise`. This will cause your `catch` function to run. `err => {console.log(err)}` returns undefined and so res will be undefined too.

In this case:

```
let res = await axios.post( '/db/imageUpload', {
  formImageData, 
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  return 'REJECTED';
})
```

`res` will always either be the result of `axios.post` or `'REJECTED'` if an error has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! So as you wrote the answer is NO, there are no cases in which the variable "res" will be requested before getting the value from the `await`.

Comment: ( I upvoted but I have no rep to make it visible, sorry! :) )

Comment: Do you and Madara think I should update the question?

Comment: No, the question is file but you could mark my answer as correct

Comment: how do I do that? I only know how to upvote EDIT: did it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `await` keyword is used for unwrapping promises (which `axios.post()` returns). The following two are roughly equivalent in all cases:

```
const a = await p();
b(a);

// and

p().then(a => b(a));
```

In your specific case, you've added a `.catch()` handler, which doesn't return anything. So in the case of an error, you'll get a `console.log` of the error (which you should change to `console.error()` at the very least), and `res` will be assigned with `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use try catch with await

```
async imageUpload(id) {
  let formImageData = new FormData()
  formImageData.append('file', this.formImageFile)
  try {
    let res = await axios.post( '/db/imageUpload', {
      formImageData, 
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    })    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  alert(res)
}
```

Comment: Why should he? `.catch` is perfectly fine and more readable. Also this is not what he asked.

Comment: A try catch block is not the best solution in my oppinion. With .then() and .chatch() you can chain multiple error handlers and even use one .catch() after every .then() in the chain. That makes error catching much more precise than single try...catch. If you have multiple Errors inside a try...catch block, it's much harder to handle the source of the Error. With new Promise().then().catch().then().catch() you know exactly where the error happens.